# Error with Angular ag-grid: "Could not find component class XXX, did you forget to configure this component"

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am getting this error from Chrome when running an ag-grid application. Basically, I have following

```
export class CustomHeader implements IHeaderAngularComp {
  private params: any;


  @ViewChild('menuButton', { read: ElementRef }) public menuButton;

  agInit(params): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  onMenuClicked() {
    this.params.showColumnMenu(this.menuButton.nativeElement);
  }

  refresh(params: IHeaderParams): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

...

ColumnDefs = {
    ...
     {
        field: "A column", editable: false, sortable: false, width: 90,
        type: 'stringColumn', centered: true, pinned: 'left',
        headerComponent: CustomHeader,
        headerComponentParams: {
          template: `
            <div ref="eLabel" class="lmn-form-group">
              <input ref="eCheck" type="checkbox">
              <span>Use This</span>
            </div>
          `
        }
     },
    ...
}
```

The Chrome says it does not recognize this CustomHeader:

> Could not find component class CustomHeader {
> agInit(params) {
> this.params = params;
> }
> onMenuClicked() {
> this.params.showColumnMenu(this.menuButton.nativeElement);
> }
> refresh(params) {
> return true;
> }
> }, did you forget to configure this component?"

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Is there a `@Component` decorator on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen the [example in the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-header/#example-header-component)?

Note that you also need to provide the `[frameworkComponents]` grid property so that the grid knows to use the header component:

```
 this.frameworkComponents = { agColumnHeader: CustomHeader };
```

Comment: I was exactly copying from the document. I tried adding frameworkComponents = { agColumnHeader: CustomHeader }; But same error appears.

Comment: Did you add the Header Component to the app.module.ts file?

Answer (score 4):

If you come here in 2022 and you are not using the latest version ag-grid, do check the correct version documents here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/

For me at version 25.3, still need to use frameworkComponents as @Shuheb said, but the latest version 27.3 docs do not have this property any more.

As the 25.3 doc says, There are two ways to register custom components:

- By name.
- Direct reference.

1. By Name

```js
export class AppComponent {
  frameworkComponents: [
      'cubeComponent': CubeComponent
  ];          
  columnDefs: [
      {
          headerName: "Cube",
          field: "value",
          cellRenderer: 'cubeComponent',     
      }
  ]

  //...other properties & methods
}
```

2. By Direct Reference

```js
export class AppComponent {
  columnDefs: [
      {
          headerName: "Cube",
          field: "value",
          cellRendererFramework: CubeComponent,     
      }
  ]

  //...other properties & methods
}
```